# Trying to import from CSV to wordpress db

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, encoding

Im using the following to import lines from txt file

```
$fp = fopen($storagename, 'r');

while ( !feof($fp) ){
     $line = fgets($fp, 2048);
     $data = str_getcsv($line, '\t');

    $new_line = array(
        "clinic_id" => $data[0],
        "type" => trim($data[2]),
        "date" => $mysql_date,
        "time_from" => $mysql_time_from,
        "time_to" => $mysql_time_to,
        "doc_licsense"=> trim($data[7])
    );
    $wpdb->insert
}
```

Here is a sample of a single line

```
Array ( 
[clinic_id] => 20 
[type] => A 
[date] => 2016-04-04 
[time_from] => 16:00:00 
[time_to] => 16:15:00 
[doc_licsense] => 10352 
)
```

Line is inserted to the DB as

```
Array ( 
[clinic_id] => 0 
[type] => A 
[date] => 0 
[time_from] => 0 
[time_to] => 0 
[doc_licsense] => 0 
)
```

I think it might have something to do with the encoding but i cant figure that out

Comment: have you tried set an array of formats _(%s, %d or %f)_ to be mapped to each of the values in _$new_line Array_ when you calling _$wpdb->insert_ ?

Comment: Yes i did I think it is some kind of an encoding issue, when i var_dump($data[0]) I get string(5) even though it should be string(2)